# How can I simplify this UNION?

Tags: mysql, join, select, union

Here's the case - I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT rp.post_id, pm.meta_value AS premiere_date
        FROM wp_related_people AS rp
        JOIN wp_posts AS p ON rp.post_id = p.ID
        JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE
            rp.person_id = 494166 AND
            rp.role = 'director' AND
            pm.meta_key = 'htk_premiere_date'
        )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT rp.post_id, '' AS premiere_date
        FROM wp_related_people AS rp
        JOIN wp_posts AS p ON rp.post_id = p.ID
        JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE
            rp.person_id = 494166 AND
            rp.role = 'director'
    )
    ORDER BY (premiere_date IS NULL), premiere_date DESC
) AS element_ids
```

The above query works as intended but, as those two inner SELECTs are fairly similar, I was wondering if there is a way to merge them into a single query?

Here's the background:
This is related to a WordPress database, expanded with custom tables. I need to get IDs of elements, sorted by htk_premiere_date meta key value. This key & its value is stored in wp_postmeta - table that has the following columns: meta_id (not important here), post_id, meta_key & meta_value. The point is, I need to sort all IDs in the following pattern:

1. First, IDs that have this htk_premiere_date key set and it's assigned a date value (so sorted by date).
2. Second, IDs that does not have the htk_premiere_date meta value set, but the key has its row in the wp_postmeta table.
3. Third - and this is basically the source of the whole problem - if a post ID does not have a row in wp_postmeta table for htk_premiere_date key, it should be treated as in point 2. - so as if it has the key but no value assigned to it.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner query should look like

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    rp.post_id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN pm.meta_key = 'htk_premiere_date' THEN pm.meta_value 
        ELSE '' 
    END
    AS premiere_date
        FROM wp_related_people AS rp
        JOIN wp_posts AS p ON rp.post_id = p.ID
        JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE
            rp.person_id = 494166 AND
            rp.role = 'director'
```

[REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: Works great, thank you! I only replaced the '' with NULL as '' were giving me SQL warnings.

Answer (score 1):

in ANSI SQL the DISTINCT is totally pointless here. UNION automatically filters duplicates:

```
test=# SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

There is a sharp distinction between UNION and UNION ALL:

```
test=# SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
        1
(2 rows)
```

in your case the second subselect can never have the same rows as the first one (due to the empty column) so UNION ALL is already definitely fine here (saving a pointless duplication filter).

Comment: Actually, after UNION I get two columns (post_id, premiere_date) so the IDs in the first one are often duplicated. That's why I use SELECT DISTINCT in the outer query.